# Flutter: get past purchases on Android

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, android-inapp-purchase, flutter-in-app-purchase

I'm refactoring `in_app_purchases` and I'm trying to get the past purchases. According to the documentation:

> The InAppPurchaseConnection.queryPastPurchases method has been
> removed. Instead, you should use InAppPurchase.restorePurchases. This
> method emits each restored purchase on the
> InAppPurchase.purchaseStream, the PurchaseDetails object will be
> marked with a status of PurchaseStatus.restored

But the example they provide doesn't get the past purchases, it adds the one you buy at that moment.

I moved from this:

```
final QueryPurchaseDetailsResponse purchaseResponse =
        await _connection.queryPastPurchases();
```

to this:

```
final Stream<List<PurchaseDetails>> purchaseUpdated = inAppPurchase.purchaseStream;

print(purchaseUpdated.toList());
```

I tried the above but the list is empty and for sure my user has purchases as I can show here when I try to buy the same version I bought before:
[image]

How could get a `List` from previous purchases?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm stuck on Android specifically where my device has a subscription but I can't get the purchase details of it.

Comment: yes, it's resolved down below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `listen` to the `purchaseStream` like [this code](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/d5b65742487f64166a73f116b925ce800c45dcd7/packages/in_app_purchase/in_app_purchase/example/lib/main.dart#L61-L69) in the example:

```dart
    final Stream<List<PurchaseDetails>> purchaseUpdated =
        _inAppPurchase.purchaseStream;
    _subscription = purchaseUpdated.listen((purchaseDetailsList) {
      _listenToPurchaseUpdated(purchaseDetailsList);
    }, onDone: () {
      _subscription.cancel();
    }, onError: (error) {
      // handle error here.
    });
```

All the purchased items will be added to this stream, so you need to add all the results to your list like below:

```dart
    final List<PurchaseDetails> purchasedList = [];
    final Stream<List<PurchaseDetails>> purchaseUpdated =
        _inAppPurchase.purchaseStream;
    _subscription = purchaseUpdated.listen((purchaseDetailsList) {

      purchasedList.addAll(purchaseDetailsList);

    }, onDone: () {
      _subscription.cancel();
    }, onError: (error) {
      // handle error here.
    });
```

Now you can use `purchasedList` as previous purchases. By the way, all the newly purchased items will be also added to that stream and `purchasedList`.

**UPDATE:** After the above steps, you need to call [`_inAppPurchase.restorePurchases()`](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/d5b65742487f64166a73f116b925ce800c45dcd7/packages/in_app_purchase/in_app_purchase/lib/in_app_purchase.dart#L189-L211) to get the previous purchases, all the previous purchases will be added to `purchasedList` by the `purchaseStream`.

Comment: I also tried that but it doesn't go in when I declare it. It liste for future purchases and I need to get the previous ones

Comment: The `purchaseStream` will listen to the previous and future purchases as mentioned in [this](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/d5b65742487f64166a73f116b925ce800c45dcd7/packages/in_app_purchase/in_app_purchase/lib/in_app_purchase.dart#L189-L211) @Dani

Comment: btw, you know how can I wait for the purchases? I don't see how to make that function async

Comment: I mean, I know it's a Stream but I'd need to get the past purchases from a Future when the app loads to perform other actions as I was doing before with old version of the package: await this.inAppPurchase.queryPastPurchases();

Comment: I think the old way is not possible with `stream` method. Btw, you shouldn't use that way to restore your previous purchases because AppStore will reject them. Instead, you should create a Restore button and call `.restorePurchases` when the user taps it. The previous purchases will be persisted automatically by the package, so you don't need to call `.restorePurchases` after it has been restored, it will be added to the `purchaseStream` in the next it's opened.

Comment: ok so that means I need to refactor my logic, just checking. Thanks again

Comment: any chance you could also know about this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69150775/flutter-get-past-purchases-on-ios

Comment: You can check your post. I have answered.