# Flutter: get past purchases on iOS

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, flutter-in-app-purchase

Everything is working on Android with the new implementation of `in_app_purchase` (https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) but on iOS I don't get past purchases. Following the documentation I don't see anything special.

My code is:

```
final Stream<List<PurchaseDetails>> purchaseUpdated =
          inAppPurchase.purchaseStream;

      _subscription = purchaseUpdated.listen((purchaseDetailsList) {
        if (purchaseDetailsList.isEmpty) {
          Provider.of<AdState>(context, listen: false).toggleAds(context, true);
        } else {
          Provider.of<AdState>(context, listen: false)
              .toggleAds(context, false);
          this.purchases.addAll(purchaseDetailsList);
          listenToPurchaseUpdated(purchaseDetailsList);
        }
      }, onDone: () {
        _subscription.cancel();
      }, onError: (error) {
        // handle error here.
      });

      inAppPurchase.restorePurchases();
```

It just doesn't go in and if I try to buy same product I get this error:

> There is a pending transaction for the same product identifier. Please
> either wait for it to be finished or finish it manually using
> `completePurchase` to avoid edge cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a ticket on the repo and it was fixed on version 1.0.9:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/89950

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `_inAppPurchase.completePurchase(purchase);` to complete it. [Code here:](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/d5b65742487f64166a73f116b925ce800c45dcd7/packages/in_app_purchase/in_app_purchase/example/lib/main.dart#L245-L247)

```dart
if (purchase.pendingCompletePurchase) {
  _inAppPurchase.completePurchase(purchase);
}
```

You also need to call it every time your app is opened to ensure that all payments have been completed, **it's very important**, remember to check `purchase.pendingCompletePurchase` before calling it.

Btw, I prefer `flutter_inapp_purchase` over `in_app_purchase` because I also had some unexpected issues with it in iOS.

Comment: But if I do that, purchases is always empty. I don't have any yet. I'd need to listen for them first and get the restored one as I do on Android. About the other package I experienced in the past some problems with abandoned packages, despite they were better than the officials. I know that one is better than the one I'm using but I feel more secure with the official one.

Comment: I was checking also the examples they have on the repo and it's quite confusing: there are a project for Android, for iOS and for both. The breaking changes were too much I think, I got everything on place already

Comment: also the info is quite inconsistent. Depending where you check, InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition.enablePendingPurchases(); is only for Android or for both platforms. For both: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-in-app-purchases#5 For just Android: https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase

Comment: `InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition.enablePendingPurchases();` is only needs for Android, it do nothing in iOS so you can add it in both platforms, but `_inAppPurchase.completePurchase(purchase);` needs for both.  And yes, the package is very confusing, I have spent a lot of time understanding it but it still has issues at the end. About the other package, I also feel the same to you but it's the only way to make the app work, so I will refactor it later when the official one works better.

Comment: You can take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/85529), it's the same as you're having.

Comment: I opened another one here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/89950 If I don't get any help today I will switch to the other package and that's it

Comment: well, the documentation on the other plugin is not updated  non-null