# How do i get past purchases in In App Purchase flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I've developed application with in app purchase functionality. And for that i used [in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) package. In previous version i'm getting past purchases. but recently i updated my version for that package. After that change i'm not getting past purchase history.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69150775/flutter-get-past-purchases-on-ios please refer to this ... it might help you

Comment: thanks. But i already checked with that. But it not works.!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After full day of struggle, Finally found solution for this issue.! So, basically package not provide us anything regards this except `restorePurchase()` method. We have to use other way,

1. Use third party. (Which all are paid and very complex).
2. Use own database. Such as, **Firebase**, **sqflite** or etc.

Comment: Yep. that's the solution. I'm amazed that official plugin doesn't mention this. And all other "answers" are aimed to sell Revenue-Cat service. Yeah, I know it's freemium, but it doesn't count as an answer to a technical question.